# Is there any public API or library to get the list of GCP zones and regions name

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to use GCP regions and zones in a dropdown, If any changes are done by GCP for that I need to update directly through an API.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this curl:

curl 
'https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/Your-Project/zones?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' 
--header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' 
--header 'Accept: application/json' 
--compressed

[Public documentation reference](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/zones/list)